# Facebook simple php authentication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am new to the facebook api. I had written the following code after reading the fb developers documentation:

```
<?php

require_once("php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = '(my app id)';   //correct in actual code
$config[‘secret’] = '(my app secret)';  //correct in actual code
$config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user=$facebook->getUser();

if($user==0)
{
$params = array(
'redirect_uri' => 'http://mydomain.com/facebook/php_index.php'
);

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo $login_url."<br/><br/>";
echo '<div class="notice">You need to <a href="' . $login_url . '" onclick="top.location.href = \'' . $login_url . '\';">authenticate first</a>.</div>';
}
else
{
echo $user;
}

?>
```

The domain & url seetings are correct in fb apps page. But still on clicking the login link it shows `An error occurred. Please try later.`

Can somebody please help me out. thanks in advance.

Comment: If  your domain is starts with ip address(192.176....) it wont work. Try it using live server  url 'http://mydomain.com/' in browser.

Comment: @Jusnit I am using free hosting on x10hosting. Its is mydomain.x10.mx

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know. I only want to say add only normal domains, but not localhost domains. In this case you are using sub-domain `sub.domain.com` would works

Comment: Here is a similar question, check out the comments here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196247/facebook-connect-an-error-occurred-please-try-again-later

Comment: What is your $login_url? What is the actual URL in the URL bar and what is the result of var_dump($login_url); ?

Comment: Is it error 191? If it is, search it through stackoverflow and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't setup your preferences of your addon in the API. In my case I get this message if I had the wrong path, incorrect login URL and wrong domain in the application settings. Some description of Facebook can be found in their [getting started guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#canvas)

Edit: It is the canvas preference page. You have to choose the option above "Website" instead

Comment: ok, yeah got it, had made a silly mistake. actually had shifted the code to a new url in the same domain.

Comment: @Charley  P.: Thank your for your edit. I was not concentrated enough to avoid some mistakes :(